# Get src and content from a variable

Tags: php

I'm new to php and and i need help with something. 
I need to divide the image and the content from this variable. It has a image and the description.

```
$content = "<a href="/pin/211106301253428599/">
<img src="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/192x/8d/97/f5/8d97f59de2c2d5d8d83fa61f1f4ad7a5.jpg"></a>
No matter where or why you travel, there's always something wonderfully new to be found! <a href="/search?q=quote" class="pintag" title="#quote search Pinterest">#quote</a>";
```

I know this is something simple but please help me. I need the image in a variable and the content with the link in another..

Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes embedded in the string.

Comment: You should use a DOM parsing library to get information from HTML data.

Comment: You need to use double quotes carefully, may be you can use single quote also.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar says, you should use a DOM parsing library.

You may find very useful this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Its use is similar to a jQuery parsing, and you only have to read doc to know how to use it (very good examples => http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Example:

```
$content = "<a href="/pin/211106301253428599/">
<img src="http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/192x/8d/97/f5/8d97f59de2c2d5d8d83fa61f1f4ad7a5.jpg"></a>
No matter where or why you travel, there's always something wonderfully new to be found! <a href="/search?q=quote" class="pintag" title="#quote search Pinterest">#quote</a>";

$html = str_get_html($content);

$image = $html->find('img');
$links = $html->find('a');
```

And you'll have what you want in $image and $links, :D

Comment: SimpleHtmlDom is a slow memory hog with a rather poor codebase. Consider one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php/3577662#3577662

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out them, :D. I answered SimpleHtmlDom because I've used it and it worked, with no memory problem (just parsing small pages, thought), and because I didn't know about the other. Thanks Gordon for pointing more, XD